# How do I find the selector, for .click in Nightmare.js?

Tags: css, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to use Nightmare.js to automate some scraping of a webpage. I'm a sysadmin, I'm not very knowledgable with Node.js or CSS.

I've been able to get Nightmare to input and click on a few buttons to get me logged in - I found the selector by using Chrome dev tools, Inspect. Unfortunately, what Nightmare needs, or I think it needs, isn't paste-able? For example, the login username box I'm working with, this is what worked in Nightmare:

```
.insert('input#username.form-control', 'username')
```

In Chrome Dev Tools, in Elements, that's what hovers over the GUI element, and is the first line in "Properties", but if I "Copy selector", I get

`#username`

Copy Xpath:

`//*[@id="username"]`

Copy element:

`<input class="form-control" type="text" cols="60" placeholder="Email (or username)" required="" name="username" id="username" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"  background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">`

How do I translate from any of those, to what Nightmare.js can use? I'm a bit out to sea.

Like I said, I got that one to work, by manually copying the first thing in "Properties", but why isn't that something I can copy from Chrome Dev Tools? Obviously, Chrome and Nightmare have different ideas of what a selector is and I don't even know how to begin to reconcile them. When I try searching for CSS Selector and Node.js, I find suggestions to use more stuff from Github like Cheerio.js (which I have not done), rather than shed any light on what I'm actually doing wrong.

Concrete example of what's not working: I have a button I can't click.
Copy element:

`<button tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" class="dpl-button___jGBcY button-tertiary-colors button-font-size button-font-weight button-line-height button-text-transform font-family-primary button-pad button-shadow border-radius-button">Policy Tester</button>`

I'm trying different approaches based on what I'm finding here and on Google and not making headway. I'm clearly missing something.

Trying  `.click('button#Policy Tester')` won't work, apparently because there's a space in it.

Trying `.click('button[tabindex="0"]')` gives "unable to find element by selector".

Trying `.click('button.dpl-button___jGBcY.button-tertiary-colors.button-font-size.button-font-weight.button-line-height.button-text-transform.font-family-primary.button-pad.button-shadow.border-radius-button')` is also unable to find the element.

Comment: Unless of course @karthick is correct and Nightmare is true to its name in that it's running before the DOM is fully loaded, in which case you get to rely on either the Nightmare or you get to extend it for them.

Comment: Nightmare has a ".wait" command, that might be part of my solution. I also note that Electron doesn't have right-click "inspect element", which is annoying. It has the Chrome dev tools so I can eventually drill down to an element, but what the heck.

Comment: What code? My nightmare script? No, I'm not adding *anything*. I'm trying to interact with someone else's webpage. As I said in my question, that string is part of what's there if I "copy element" from the dev tools. Your questions are, sadly, only confusing me more.

Comment: Please see my 'Revised UPDATE' in my answer below and let us know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the background but I believe your question can be condensed to asking what jQuery selector can be used to access `<button tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" class="dpl-button___jGBcY button-tertiary-colors button-font-size button-font-weight button-line-height button-text-transform font-family-primary button-pad button-shadow border-radius-button">Policy Tester</button>`.

This will access the element `$('button[class^="dpl-button_"]')`. Downside here is that there's nothing unique about this class, which means all* elements that have this class will have your click event applied to them.

Note that this element contains multiple attributes, that means there are a number of options here. However, know that depending on which attribute you target there very well may be other elements in the DOM that have the same attribute so the key here is to find something unique. Most of the time we can apply an ID to an element, and as long as the ID is unique in the DOM you can simply use `$('#YourUniqueId')` to access that particular element and no others.

One thing to note about what you put in your post that is incorrect is that you attempted to access the element by using the elements text as the ID (e.g., `.click('button#Policy Tester')`). The elements text is not it's ID.

Here are a couple of links that will likely help those needing a solid reference on selectors:

- [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference)

**Revised UPDATE**

Researched Nightmare.js a bit, please try`click('button.dpl-button___jGBcY')` to find the element.

Comment: Interesting - if I type `document.querySelector('button[class^="dpl-button_"]')` into Chrome dev tools console, it only returns one result, and it's a different button from the one i'm having trouble with.

Comment: @mfinni - Apparently you have more than one element on the page that contains that class, ``...querySelector(...` will return the first element found, that is the intended behavior for `querySelector`. Please refer to the note I left in this regard. As mentioned above you'll need to find something unique about an element for the `querySelector` to isolate your DOM query to the element you're looking for. Also, as mentioned above, apply an ID to the element and query for that ID.

Comment: @mfinni - Also, may not be my place to question this but why is it that you're loading jQuery then using pure javascript functions like `querySelector`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by asking if I'm loading jQuery, etc. What I've said I've done is everything I've done. My question describes my nightmare click statements, my comment is something I tried in dev tools console. I'm not loading jQuery; I assume nightmare and/or node does that for me?

Comment: I don't control the page I'm trying to interact with, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I don't know what jQuery is. The tools i have to work with are Node.js (for Nightmare), or the dev tools. Karthick suggested i use the dev tools console to test for elements using document.queryselector(), how do I use that with the syntax you provided for $('button:contains("Policy Tester")') ? It doesn't work if I enter `document.querySelector($('button:contains("Policy Tester")') )`

Comment: I know that I'm probably asking for this in baby steps, spoonfeeding. I said up front I don't know much about Node or CSS. If you're giving me syntax that doesn't work in the tools I'm working with, it's just confusing me more.

Comment: He's correct in that regard. And the selector above won't work in this situation because I finally looked at nightmare and confirmed that Nightmare is headless, meaning that even if you did know what jQuery was you wouldn't be able to use it and lastly, per their documentation we've been going at this all wrong, I'm going to drop this answer for an updated much smaller answer.

Comment: That clicks a different button unfortunately.

Comment: Aha - but this worked: ``  .click("#content_container > div > div > div > div > div.sub-header > button")` That's the selector of the desired button.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to get the proper selector. Using inspect elements and so on.

## Way 1

"copy selector" from "inspect element", most of the time it'll work. You don't copy the element, you copy the **selector**

## Way 2

Here is a simple way to do it in chrome.

- Install [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en)
- Then on whatever page you want to scrape, open selectorgadget and pick the element.
- There you got your needed element selector.
- Use it.

[image]